# Get Pepper's IP using QiSDK from Android app on Pepper, NAOqi 2.9

Tags: pepper, nao-robot

I have the Pepper robot running NAOqi 2.9, which is the version using QiSDK to create Android applications for its tablet.

I currently have to get Pepper's *head's* IP in my Android app, which can be easily made as a manual input, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this programatically, since the tablet knows the head's IP, always displaying it in the notification bar, alongside the tablet's IP.

On step 5 on [Connecting to a real robot](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/running_application.html) they say you can do this manually.

> How to find the IP address?

> On the tablet of the robot, display the notifications (swipe down from the top of the screen) and look for the following logo:

But that's just the Getting Started page. I've also looked into the [Javadocs of the qisdk api](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/qisdk/index.html?com/) but didn't find anything related to the head's IP.

I was wondering if someone knows a way I could do this, not necessarily using QiSDK, since it doesn't seem to support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most straightforward solution, but you can access the head computer from the tablet through SSH, since the head is connected to the tablet by USB and has a static IP address of `192.168.100.80`. Then you can get the IP address of the head using `ifconfig`.

To do this in Java, I used [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), but any java SSH implementation should be fine.

### Installing JSch

Download jsch-0.1.55.jar from [here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). Create a new folder `libs` in your app directory and save the jar in there. Then add the following to your build.gradle under dependencies:

```java
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

### Command for getting IP address

Thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560412/displaying-ip-address-on-eth0-interface), you can do some processing on the `ifconfig` output to get the IP address of Pepper's head on the wifi network.
Note: I'm not able to test this on a physical Pepper at the moment, so please check this first by SSHing into Pepper and running the command. Mainly check that `wlan0` is the right name for the network device.

```sh
ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

### Running this command in Java

```java
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.InputStream;

// Create SSH session
jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession("nao", "192.168.100.80", 22);
session.setPassword("nao");

// Avoid asking for key confirmation
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(prop);

String command = "ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1";

session.connect();
ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
channelssh.setCommand(command);
InputStream stdout = channelssh.getInputStream();
// Execute command
channelssh.connect();
// Get output
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
int bytesRead = input.read();
while (bytesRead != -1) {
    output.append((char) bytesRead);
    bytesRead = input.read();
}
// close SSH channel
channelssh.disconnect();

// Here's the IP address of the head, formatted as a string
String headIP = output.toString();
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I had no idea I could connect via usb0 interface's IP with SSH from the tablet to the robot. This was exactly what I needed, an IP that will not change, even if the the WiFi network changes. The usb0 IP was a different one for me, I don't think it's 192.168.100.80 for everyone (I got it ssh-ing from laptop over wifi), and I couldn't get JSch to work, but sshj worked (more kex algorithm support). Thank you so much!